# Extract all values for a particular Key in a list of dictionaries - using robot framework

Tags: python, list, dictionary, robotframework

I am not getting how to extract all values for a Key "name" in the below list of dictionaries using robot framework. Please help me out.

```
{'data': [{'attributes': {'name': 'Acura'},
           'id': 'de3fe2a2-eaa1-45d8-8d6b-298e0b2d0666',
           'type': 'brands'},
          {'attributes': {'name': 'Alfa Romeo'},
           'id': '52b33ad8-71ab-4fdb-b877-a6080e86439c',
           'type': 'brands'},
          {'attributes': {'name': 'Audi'},
           'id': '5f627b7a-193a-40a0-9db7-b8b504177435',
           'type': 'brands'},
          {'attributes': {'name': 'BMW'},
           'id': 'dad04367-2248-45b3-b523-0be7cc7bfbad',
           'type': 'brands'},
          {'attributes': {'name': 'Buick'},
           'id': '64f77989-3007-41f5-b5c4-8cb5f4a25d45',
           'type': 'brands'},
          {'attributes': {'name': 'Cadillac'},
           'id': 'a457ba4e-5f74-4b9a-9316-d26962284983',
           'type': 'brands'},
          {'attributes': {'name': 'Chevrolet'},
           'id': '118e4876-993d-4ad0-91f4-ae3d25b1e5f5',
           'type': 'brands'}],
 'meta': {'total': 48}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43825171/robot-framework-variable-class-file-with-triple-nested-dictionary-is-not-dot-not) the dot notation issue when referring to a regular Python dictionary. This was solved by converting the regular Python Dict to the robot specific DotDict.

Alternatively, if the above data is static, you could consider importing this from a [Yaml file](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#variable-file-as-yaml), which will also allow you to use the robot dot notation.

With respect to cycling and fetching the names then assuming the dictionary is assigned to variable D and stored in a file called `dict.py` then this will allow you to fetch the name:

```
*** Settings ***
Variables    dict.py
*** Test Cases ***
test
    Log To Console    \n    
    :FOR    ${node}    IN    @{d['data']}
    \    Log To Console    ${node['attributes']['name']}
```

Which will result in the following output:

```
test                                                                  

Acura
Alfa Romeo
Audi
BMW
Buick
Cadillac
Chevrolet
| PASS |
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this,

```
>>> [ i['attributes']['name'] for i in a['data']]
['Acura', 'Alfa Romeo', 'Audi', 'BMW', 'Buick', 'Cadillac', 'Chevrolet']
```

where `a` is name of the dictionary.

Answer (score 3):

Let `d` is the dictionary'name. Names can be extracted usind the below code:

```
names = [a['attributes']['name'] for a in d['data']]
```

Results:

```
print names
[u'Acura', u'Alfa Romeo', u'Audi', u'BMW', u'Buick', u'Cadillac', u'Chevrolet']
```